# \include'd tables show up on separate pages. How can I fit them on a single page?

Tags: tables

When I insert two tables with `\include` into my `main.tex` file, each table floats to a separate page. I would like to fit them into one page and mesh with the rest of the document. I can do that when the code for tables is contained in the `main.tex` file but obviously this complicates maintenance of the document tremendously.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\insert` ?? where is that defined I have never seen that command.

Comment: If you mean `\include`, then that's normal behavior; use `\input`; however a minimal example is necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I did mean \include. I changed to \input and indeed the placement is now two tables per page plus text. Thank you, I need to find out about the differences between these two commands.

Comment: [When should I use \input vs. \include?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include) and welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `\include` issues a new page before reading in the file, whereas `\input` acts as if the file were directly included at that point.

I use `\include` for things like chapters which are on a new page anyway, and `\input` for parts of the document that may be in multiple different documents or otherwise not directly related to the current file.

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include) and [this page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Modular_Documents) have more details.